# Convert list of matrices to a single data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
 data=read.table(text="region     plot    species
 1          1A      A_B  
 1          1B      B_C
 1          1C      A_B
 1          1D      C_D
 2          2A      B_C
 2          2A      E_F
 2          2B      B_C
 2          2B      E_F     
 2          2C      E_F
 2          2D      B_C
 3          3A      A_B
 3          3B      A_B",stringsAsFactors=F,h=T)
```

And from that data frame made a list of matrices using:

```
sublist=NA
for (i in unique(data$region)){   
  sublist[i]<-list(subset(data, data[,1] == i))  
  print(i)
}

 results = list()
 for (r in unique(data$region)){
  myset<-split(sublist[[r]][[3]],sublist[[r]][[2]])
  output<- matrix(NA, nrow = length(myset), ncol = length(myset))
  rownames(output)<-colnames(output)<-unique(sublist[[r]][[2]])
  for (j in 1:(length(myset)-1)){
    for (i in (j+1):length(myset)){
    output[i,j]=sum(myset[[j]] %in% myset[[i]])
     }
   }
 results[[r]]=output
 }
```

Here is how the output appears (Note: they vary in dimensions and contain NAs):

```
 [[1]]
   1A 1B 1C 1D
1A NA NA NA NA
1B  0 NA NA NA
1C  1  0 NA NA
1D  0  0  0 NA

[[2]]
   2A 2B 2C 2D
2A NA NA NA NA
2B  2 NA NA NA
2C  1  1 NA NA
2D  1  1  0 NA

[[3]]
   3A 3B
3A NA NA
3B  1 NA
```

I want to apply a function to this list of matrices that changes the format to one dataframe. One column of the dataframe would be the matrix element, the second would be the row and column dimensions of the matrix  and the third column a `freq` column that contains the matrix fill values. For this example the output would look like: (Note: NAs are not considered.

```
output<-
      x     y       freq
      1     1A_1B     0     
      1     1A_1C     1
      1     1A_1D     0
      1     1B_1C     0    
      1     1B_1D     0 
      1     1C_1D     0
      2     2A_2B     2     
      2     2A_2C     1
      2     2A_2D     1
      2     2B_2C     1    
      2     2B_2D     1 
      2     2C_2D     0
      3     3A_3B     1
```

I am not opposed to more efficient code that converts the first/original dataframe to this output dataframe to circumvent the loop and list of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `lapply`.

get a list of data.frames

```
myList <- lapply(seq_along(results), function(i) {
       # get matrix of non NA positions
       pos <- which(!is.na(results[[i]]), arr.ind=TRUE)
       # return data.frame for given list item
       data.frame(x=i,
                  y=paste(rownames(results[[i]])[pos[,1]], colnames(results[[i]])[pos[,2]]),
                  freq=results[[i]][pos])
})
```

The first variable of the data.frame is the index of the `lapply` iteration. The second is constructed by pasting the rownames and colnames of the matrix in the list using the matrix of non-NA positions. The third variable is constructed using matrix subsetting where extraction.

then `do.call` with `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, myList)
   x     y freq
1  1 1B 1A    0
2  1 1C 1A    1
3  1 1D 1A    0
4  1 1C 1B    0
5  1 1D 1B    0
6  1 1D 1C    0
7  2 2B 2A    2
8  2 2C 2A    1
9  2 2D 2A    1
10 2 2C 2B    1
11 2 2D 2B    1
12 2 2D 2C    0
13 3 3B 3A    1
```

Comment: I know it may be challenging to trouble shoot without the real data, but do you have any idea why I may be getting this error message:` Error in seq_len(B.list) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:In seq_len(B.list) : first element used of 'length.out' argument`

Comment: darn it another typo. It should be `seq_along`.

Comment: Do you have anyway to add an argument to the code you provided above that removes like comparisons? For example, in the event y= 1A _1A or y= 2B_2B I do not want the same (plots in this case) to be compared.

Comment: After `pos <- which(!is.na(results[[i]]), arr.ind=TRUE)` you could add the line `pos <- pos[pos[, 1] != pos[, 2], ]` to drop any non-NA diagonal elements.

Comment: Great. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(region,species) %>% 
  filter(n()>1)%>%
  summarize(y=list(combn(plot,2, paste, collapse="_"))) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  group_by(region,y) %>% 
  summarize(freq=n())

  region     y  freq
   <int> <chr> <int>
1      1 1A_1C     1
2      2 2A_2B     2
3      2 2A_2C     1
4      2 2A_2D     1
5      2 2B_2C     1
6      2 2B_2D     1
7      3 3A_3B     1
```

Comment: Do you have anyway to add an argument to the code you provided above that removes like comparisons? For example, in the event y= 1A _1A or y= 2B_2B I do not want the same (plots in this case) to be compared.

Comment: By the way I should say thank you and that your code was a perfect more efficient way to my question. I accepted the other answer because the answer addressed the question title. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're welcome @Danielle! To remove duplicates, try adding `filter(!duplicated(plot))` after first `group_by`

Comment: That returns `Error: n < m` . If you have the time, would you mind taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808793/conditional-statement-in-dplyr-tidyverse-function-to-exclude-comparisons-among-s?noredirect=1#comment76599458_44808793   I have updated this question to fit my current issues with this.

Comment: what does the filter(n()>1) do?

Comment: ` filter(n()>1)` remove region/species group with less than 2 elements (no pair of species in a region)